# H2 SQL Date Comparison

Tags: sql, datetime, h2

In an H2 database on a column of type TIMESTAMP how do I run a query

```
SELECT * FROM RECORDS WHERE TRAN_DATE < '2012/07/24'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `'2012-07-24'`

http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=dateType&search=date#date

Answer (score 1):

For me the following helped, because I also needed to compare the full timestamp with date and time:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORDS WHERE TRAN_DATE < TIMESTAMP '2020-07-24 20:00:00'
```

This may help others even if it doesn't help the questioner.