# How to select date from H2 database

Tags: database, h2

I am trying to run the following query against an H2 Database:

```
SELECT ID FROM CONTEST WHERE CONTEST_DATE = 2004-03-01;
```

I know that h2 doesn't support to_date, so how would I write this query? The CONTEST_DATE col is of type date.

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634403/h2-sql-date-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the specification of the H2 SQL Grammar (http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#date):

"A date literal. The limitations are the same as for the Java data type java.sql.Date, but for compatibility with other databases the suggested minimum and maximum years are 0001 and 9999.

Example:

DATE '2004-12-31'"

So use apostrophes, like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM CONTEST WHERE CONTEST_DATE = DATE '2004-03-01';
```

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM CONTEST WHERE CONTEST_DATE = DATE '2004-03-01';`